# Nginx normalize Accept-Encoding for better cache hit ratio

Tags: nginx, caching, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have problem with normalizing Accept-Encoding, during tests express server getting correctly normalized Accept-Encoding from nginx, but nginx didn't respect "Vary: Accept-Encoding" and when I send request with e.g. "Accept-Encoding: gzip, br" and "Accept-Encoding: gzip" I got 2 requests to express server, it should be only 1 request

nginx

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/express_cache keys_zone=express_cache:10m levels=1:2 inactive=600s max_size=100m;

map $http_accept_encoding $pwa_normalized_encoding {
    default "";
    "~*gzip" "gzip";
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

  set $pass_access_scheme $scheme;
  set $pass_server_port $server_port;
  set $best_http_host $http_host;
  set $pass_port $pass_server_port;

        location /express {
        proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_cache express_cache;
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      proxy_cache_background_update on;
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding $pwa_normalized_encoding;
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }
}
```

express server

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("encoding:", new Date().toISOString(), (req.get("Accept-Encoding")));

    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=30");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.setHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");

    setTimeout(() => {
        res.json({date: new Date().toISOString()})
    }, 300)
})
```

Comment: solution found based on https://dzx.fr/blog/how-to-configure-reverse-proxy-caching-with-nginx/